# What's the term that refers to attributes that accept no value (i.e. "checked" and "selected")?

Tags: html, terminology

The attributes `checked` and `selected`, of the `<input>` and the `<option>` tags respectively, belong to a group of attributes that don't accept a value.

What's the term that refers to that group of attributes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Boolean attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2):

> Some attributes play the role of boolean variables (e.g., the [`selected`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-selected) attribute for the [`OPTION`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION) element). Their appearance in the start tag of an element implies that the value of the attribute is "true". Their absence implies a value of "false".
>
> Boolean attributes may legally take a single value: the name of the attribute itself (e.g., `selected="selected"`)...

Answer (score 4):

> The attributes `checked` and `selected` of the `<input>` tag belong to a group of attributes that don't accept a value.

Incorrect. They accept a value that is the same as the name of the attribute.

In HTML 4 you may omit everything except the value.

> What's the term that refers to that group?

Boolean.

Comment: So the value of the "checked" attribute is "checked" and that's a boolean?